# How to get current slide and total slides in Featherlight lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, featherlight.js

In a simple [featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight) gallery, how does one get the `current slide` and `total slides`?

Demo:
http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html

I am retrieving the `featherlight` object with `$.featherlight.current()` but am not sure how to proceed.

**edit:**
I've been able to find the total slides, though not exactly ideal, through `$.featherlight.current().$source.length` *I say not exactly ideal because I believe this may vary depending on the HTML upon which featherlight is instantiated, for my own use I had to traverse the source to the appropriate level before counting*

So now I am just not sure of a good way to find the `current slide`?

**edit2:** With the help of someone on their github issue tracker (my mistake, was supposed to post here on SO), looking at the source for `navigateTo`, I was able to easily find `currentNavigation()`, and thus, the simple answer is `$.featherlight.current().currentNavigation()`

**So then the final question** is if there is a better way to find the total slide count?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, `currentNavigation()` will return the index of the current slide.

It does this by calling `slides()` (just renamed from `images()`, this question made me realize that it was not the best name), so you can use `slides().length` to get the number of slides.